# php-Mysql: ID of added row in database

Tags: php, mysql

I know we can get last insert id by this `$last_id = $conn->insert_id;`

Here is the scenario.

Suppose multiple users are inserting row in database lets say register. If
I use `$last_id = $conn->insert_id;` then it will return the correct id or not.

Because if multiple data is getting insert in database at the same time. In that case it will work or not. If not then is there anything we can do to get the ID of that specific user record.

Please advise

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a misunderstanding (actually a duplicate and asked many times)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the functions returns the last inserted id (for autoincremental id tables) by this connexion, not in the database. Others inserts doesn't count.

Reading the mysql documentation:

> For LAST_INSERT_ID(), the most recently generated ID is maintained in
>   the server on a per-connection basis. It is not changed by another
>   client.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/getting-unique-id.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Voted up. I don't understand what is wrong with my question. voted down by someone.